# Why lasers and not light?

Tags: visible-light, laser

Some laser applications consist simply concentrating light into a small spot (e.g., image projection, welding, cutting, etc.). Why are lasers used instead of a simpler light source?

Comment: Aren't lasers a very simple light source? Also, this seems to be mroe engineering than physics.

Comment: The complexity of a laser is higher than that of an arc lamp, for example. Maintenance and operation cost is also higher.

Comment: Light pointers were used a century ago, you just don't know about them because they have fallen out of favor since we now have much better digital instruments: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_galvanometer

Answer (score 2):

Lasers are *coherent* light sources, meaning that all of the light is of the same wavelength, relative phase, and direction. This is as opposed to other light sources which typically release a spectrum of wavelengths (producing white light) in all directions. Because all the light is of the same wavelength and relative phase, it is easier to work with the laser light and fine-tune it to whatever application you have. Also, lasers tend to be more energy efficient than other light sources. For example, if you wanted to create a really bright incandescent light to do welding with, such a source of light would also generate an immense amount of heat such that even if you could direct all of the light at one spot without significant losses, you'd run into other problems.

Comment: The efficiency, right, but if your objective is simply display a bright spot of light 10 m away, why use a laser?
Today, with the availability of cheap semiconductor lasers the question is out of place, but why there was no light pointers half a century ago?

Comment: I assume that you are talking about projectors there? Are you sure that those sources are actually lasers? I'm not overly familiar with the construction of such devices, but it probably just has to do with different light sources being easier to manipulate than others for these purposes.

Comment: LCD image projectors are not lasers, but light show projectors are, just as some new projector technologies. Pointers used in conferences or light sources used in sensing are lasers too.

Answer (score 0):

A traditional sphere-shaped lightbulb emits light in all directions, if you would use a lens to focus it, a great amount would be lost. The lightwaves laser emits are all parallel with each other, so I think you can focus it to one small spot a lot better than a lightsource where photons go in all directions.

Comment: You can use a simple reflector to redirect all this light and a lens to concentrate it to a small spot. Lasers also need lenses.

Comment: It is much easier to scale the output power of a laser than of another light source without massively increasing the size (for example fibre lasers can be scales to $kW$ powers and remain relatively compact). And A large light source cannot be concentrated on a single spot easily (especially not without using large amounts of space). Try to design optics that focus all light from diffuse volume source to a single spot, that is highly non-trivial.